# How to update the Button State [Enabled, Loading, Disabled] in Recycler View Using MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on an Android project and encountered an issue. I am following MVVM and Clean Code Architecture. There is a Fragment that holds RecyclerView. And Each Recycler View Item has a button. On Each button click, the request is taken to Fragment and an API endpoint is hit.

Currently, I am showing the loading progress Indicator in Fragment but I  want to change this and want to show the button state to Loading when API Endpoint is hit and keep in that loading state until the API returns the response.

As in MVVM, It's not a good practice to pass a Button view from the Recycler View item to the Fragment, then How can I call back to the RecyclerView item to update the Button state after the endpoint returns a response.

I am looking for a proper way to handle this situation.

**My Stack:**

Kotlin, Dagger2, RxJAVA, LiveData

**Visualize**

Note: A demo UI just for the sake of an idea.

As you can see I clicked on the button in Item 1 in RecyclerView and the button state is changed to Loading and when API returns a response the button will be back to a normal state.

[image]

Comment: You pass to the RecyclerView the list with the info right? So you just need to change the item in the list to say that the button now should show "Press".

Comment: I am passing a model data class to the RecyclerView, And then pressing a button to call the API. When I press the button I want to show the progress inside the button of the clicked item. But how should I inform the recyclerview item that the API returned a response and stop showing progress indicator inside button.

Comment: Best thing would be to handle the state of the button in one place. When the user clicks the button you should inform the fragment that should have registered a listener. The Fragment should call the VM that should start the operation and update the state. The state should be passed to the RecyclerView. The same thing when the operation is completed. The recyclerview should just show the state that should be kept outside the recyclerview

Comment: In a nutshell you should treat the RecyclerView like you would do if it was just a button. The Fragment would call a VM and register an observer to get the new state and then update the button.

Comment: How the Recyclerview knows which item button state will be changed to normal from loading.?

Comment: You pass the array of info to the adapter. The info specifies the state of each button. The RecyclerView does not need to know anything about what is happening. It just shows the state.

Comment: Yes I am passing the data to the RecyelerView in start of the app to populate the items. After that I am not passing any data to recyclerview, an endpoint is hit in the fragment viewmodel whenever a button is pressed on recyclerview items. I am looking how can I callback to the recyclerview that some action is performed or API returned a response and do not show the loading. Note: that returned response have nothing to do with the recyclerview items population.

Comment: the items in the array that you pass to the RecyclerView adapter should contain a field that specifies whether to show the in-progress or not. When you start/complete an asynchronous operation you update the array with the new state and you call a method like notifyItemChanged(int position) of the adapter of the RecyclerView.

Comment: Thanks @kingston. This will now help.